# Как отменить изменения внесенные при разрешении конфликта при слиянии веток?

Tags: git

Понадобилось слить одну ветку в другую. При слиянии обнаружился конфликт в одном файле. При его разрешении не так отредактировал файл. Как можно отменить изменения в файле?
Чтобы он стал таким, как был сразу после попытки слияния, попробовал сделать так

```
git checkout myfile.c
```

на что получил ответ

> error: path 'myfile.c' is unmerged

Остальное не пробовал, дабы случайно не навредить.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в каком статусе у вас находится merge. Что выдает git status ?
Если предположить, что вы только исправили код и мерж не закончили, то проще всего сделать git merge --abort и начать мерж с начала.

Comment: Да, это то что мне подойдет, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предположить, что вы только исправили код и мерж не закончили, то проще всего сделать git merge --abort и начать мерж с начала.